# problemas al sumar con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

quiero que me realice la operación dependiendo de la opción que se escoja de lista desplegable, en este caso es una suma. Se ingresan los números mediante cajas de texto.

```js
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
            var mostrar = false;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                if (mostrar == false) $("#operaciones").hide();//boton mostrar cuando das click
                $('#ingreso').click(function () {
                    console.log(total);
                });
                $('#listado').click(function () {//llama al listado de operaciones
                    switch (valor) {
                        case 1:
                            let total = parseInt($('#numero1').val()) + parseInt($('#numero2').val()); // suma los dos numeros
                            $('#respuesta').text(total);
                            break;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
**parte en HTML**
    <body>
        <button id="cambio">
            MOSTRAR
        </button>
        <form id="operaciones">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>operaciones</legend>
                <input type="text" id="numero1" name="numero1" />//pide el  numero 1
                <input type="text" id="numero2" name="numero2" autocomplete="on" />//pide el numero 2
                <select id="listado" name="listado">//listado
                    <option value="0">SELECCIONE..</option>
                    <option value="1">SUMAR</option>
                    <option value="2">RESTAR</option>
                </select>
                <button type="button" id="ingreso">
                    REALIZAR
                </button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es una pregunta sino un requerimiento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a usar el botón para mostrar y ocultar el formulario, te recomiendo hacerlo sin depender de una variable, jQuery tiene el método [.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) que lo hace de forma automática, muestra si está oculto o viceversa. Y también puedes analizar el estado del formulario para cambiar el texto del botón.

Luego, tienes un botón para realizar la operación, pero solo estás tratando de mostrar el resultado de una variable que definiste en otra función y no está disponible ahí. Lo apropiado es que se haga la operación cuando este botón reciba clic.

En caso de que quieras que también se hagan los cálculos al seleccionar una operación, entonces escucha el evento `change` del select y haz que se dispare el evento `click` del botón con [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/).

**Recomendaciónes:**

- Asegúrate de que obtienes un valor entero de los campos, `parseInt()` puede devolver un valor no numérico, por ejemplo, cuando el campo está vacío. Solo agrega `|| 0` al final para estos casos
- Si quieres permitir decimales, entonces usa `parseFloat()` en lugar de `parseInt()`
- Asigna los eventos con [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) en lugar de `.click(funcion)` o `.change(funcion)`, el código quedará más fácil de entender.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Ocultar al inicio
    $('#operaciones').hide();
    // Mostrar u ocultar operaciones al hacer clic en botón
    $('#cambio').on('click', function() {
        $('#operaciones').toggle();
        // Cambiar texto del botón de acuerdo al estado del formulario
        if($('#operaciones').css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).text('Mostrar');
        } else {
            $(this).text('Ocultar');
        }
    });
    $('#ingreso').on('click', function () {
        // Obtener valor de select o, si falla parseInt(), poner en cero
        let valor = parseInt($('#listado').val()) || 0;
        // Asegurar que se tiene un entero
        let num1 = parseInt($('#numero1').val()) || 0;
        let num2 = parseInt($('#numero2').val()) || 0;
        // Definir variable para total
        let total = 0;
        // Analizar valor del select para saber qué hacer
        switch(valor) {
            case 1:
                // Sumar
                total = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case 2:
               // Restar
               total = num1 - num2;
               break;
            default:
               // Cualquier valor no contemplado previamente
               console.log('Selecciona una operación');
        }
        // Mostrar resultado
        $('#respuesta').text(total);
    });
    // Escuchar cambios en el select para realizar la operación
    $('#listado').on('change', function() {
        // Clic en el botón
        $('#ingreso').click();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="cambio">
            MOSTRAR
        </button>
        <form id="operaciones">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>operaciones</legend>
                <input type="text" id="numero1" name="numero1" />//pide el  numero 1
                <input type="text" id="numero2" name="numero2" autocomplete="on" />//pide el numero 2
                <select id="listado" name="listado">//listado
                    <option value="0">SELECCIONE..</option>
                    <option value="1">SUMAR</option>
                    <option value="2">RESTAR</option>
                </select>
                <button type="button" id="ingreso">
                    REALIZAR
                </button>
                <div>Resultado: <span id="respuesta">0</span></div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda @Triby